# Login to Orchard on Local

Tags: orchardcms

I am a bit lost on something that I should probably know and understand...

I am playing with Orchard CMS on my local computer, trying it out. How do I re-access the admin area after I logged out? I cannot get back to the local address I was originally on...

I used WebMatrix/Visual Studio to originally set up the site.

Answer (score 5):

By default the Dashboard is accessible in `/OrchardLocal/Admin`

Comment: Also, the default theme has a link to sign back in, and once you've done that there is a link to the dashboard. Hard to miss really :)